# Hard Drive not showing

Tags: arch-linux, ntfs, external-hdd

I've got an external hard drive, formatted as NTFS and showing fine on a Windows PC. When I plug it into my Arch Linux laptop, it doesn't show with `fdisk` or `lsblk`. If running `dmesg`, I've got this :

```
[602740.532394] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[602740.550159] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0578, bcdDevice= 2.14
[602740.550178] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[602740.550184] usb 2-1: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
[602740.550189] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: JMicron
[602740.550193] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
```

but nothing more happens. I've also tried connecting the drive on all 3 different USB ports of the laptop.
I've tried to search on a few forums and on Google, but all the answers always start after
the disk is found and present in `/dev`, and I'm not really sure what to try next.

Thanks for your help

Edit :
Running `cyme -t` gives :

```
● 2.0 root hub Linux Foundation
├──○   18 0x05e3 0x0608 Hub
│  ├──○   19 0x046d 0xc328 Corded Keyboard K280e
│  └──○   20 0x413c 0x301a Dell MS116 Optical Mouse
├──○    3 0x0c45 0x6730
└──○    5 0x8087 0x0026 AX201 Bluetooth
● 3.0 root hub Linux Foundation
└──○    6 0x152d 0x0578 JMS578 SATA 6Gb/s
```

Comment: Please follow this : https://smitchell.github.io/how-to-bind-to-the-right-usb-storage-driver

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. This link seems to be for Raspbian distro, and I'm using ArchLinux (6.1.12-arch1-1). I do not have a /boot/cmdline.txt file to modify :(

Comment: You only see the USB to ATA bridge instead of the mass storage device. What is the output of `lsusb -t`?

Comment: jmicron + linux = bad experience - just search for `linux idVendor=152d, idProduct=0578` and you will see

Comment: Please edit your question to add more info, instead.

Comment: The manual is not unique to raspberry, it will work everywhere else as well.

Comment: Ubuntu https://leo.leung.xyz/wiki/How_to_disable_USB_Attached_Storage_(UAS) https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man4/usb_quirk.4freebsd.html

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize I could apply that to my system, and it worked !

Comment: Sorry for the noob question : what am I supposed to do now ? I can't find how to mark the question as resolved

Comment: You can write your own answer describing what you did to fix the issue. Credit those who helped. 24 hours later you can accept your own answer